# Headphones don't work & music automaticaly starts

Tags: music-player, speaker, earphone

I have a Samsung trend plus.
When I plug the earphones, the phone recognizes the connection and shows the earphone icon and gives the earphones connected massage. Then automaticaly starts music, which is not normal. But the sound comes from phone's speakers instead of earphones. I can barely hear the music coming from the speakers. And even in full volume setting, it has very low volume. I tried the earphones in my computer so it's not earphone problem. I tried restarting...

Comment: Did the earphone worked properly before on the mobie you are using? Is that a samsung earphone? if yes did that came inside the package or you bought it separately?

Comment: Yes earphones was working properly with my phone before. It still works properly with other devices.I also tried two different earphones.

Comment: then it should probably be a hardware(headphone jack) problem..you can replace it..

Answer (score -1):

Try using another set of headphones for your phone. If the problem persists then it's the problem with your phone's hardware.

Answer (score -1):

Its not hardware problem. But on software side. If you dont use any custom rom features and assuming you are on stock rom and havent flashed any such mods, then check your music player or any audio managers you may have in your phone. Its them that has option to auto start music upon plugging in headphones. So check your music app for such an option and disable it.
As for sound not coming through heaphones but heaphones being detected, thats again a software problem. I suggest you try changing music player app instead. Or atleast go through its settings for once. There has to be an option for something like audio priority. Would help if you be more specific and specify phone model you use, if you are rooted and on custom rom, the media player app you use.